# How can I check if ldconfig is in the PATH, using bash?

Tags: perl, bash

I have scrapped a perl snippet off the web for use in my bash scrip and for reasons too long to go into, it will be better if I could achieve what it tries to do directly in bash.

Here is the script:

```
bash stuff
...
perl <<'EOF'

use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings;

if (! can_run("ldconfig")) {
    die "you need to have ldconfig in your PATH env to proceed.\n";
}

# check if we can run some command
sub can_run {
    my ($cmd) = @_;

    #warn "can run: @_\n";
    my $_cmd = $cmd;
    return $_cmd if -x $_cmd;

    return undef;

EOF
more bash stuff
```

Basically, the question could be rephrased as , "how can I check if ldconfig is in the PATH env using bash?"

Comment: With bash you could simply do: if [ "$(which ldconfig)" ] ; then ... - it musn't be in your PATH.

Comment: The Perl script is broken. `can_run` doesn't check the PATH.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks but I don't want to use the perl script in any case and looking for bash options

Comment: @Dayo, you didn't say you weren't going to use this Perl script anymore, and you didn't say that you didn't have that code in another other of your scripts.

Comment: Got it. I currently don't use it but who knows about later. What needs to be added to fix it?

Comment: @Dayo: Could you put your "refined script" in an answer instead of the question?

Comment: It is valid to put the command with redirections in the `if` command: `if type -P ldconfig &>/dev/null; then ...` -- the shell implicitly checks the exit status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want bash's builtin `type` command:

```
if type -P ldconfig; then
  echo "ldconfig is in the PATH"
else
  echo "ldconfig is not in the PATH"
fi
```

Expressed negatively:

```
if ! type -P ldconfig; then
  echo "ldconfig is not in the PATH"
fi
```

Comment: On my system: $ type which => which is aliased to `type -path' - tho there is a /bin/which too

Comment: @glenn jackman how do I phrase it as a negative check? "if not type -P ...?" Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A more straightforward solution would be to invoke the shell and the `which` command:

```
$path = `which ldconfig`;

if ($path) {
  ...
}
```

If `ldconfig` is recognised, the path to its executable will be returned, empty output otherwise.

Or, if this Perl script is not going to do anything more than that, you can dismiss it and execute the same command from bash.

Comment: Could also add the `-x $path` to check if the file is marked as an executable.

Answer (score 0):

I refined @glenn jackman's answer to make it "quiet". It worked as it was but it output "/sbin/ldconfig" to the screen in addition to the echo when in the path. With this modification, only the echo is output:

```
type ldconfig &>/dev/null

if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "ldconfig is in the PATH"
else
  echo "ldconfig is not in the PATH"
fi
```

Thanks to all.